# UAC in mixed C# and VB.NET projects

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a C# project that references a .NET assembly built from a VB.NET project.

This VB.NET assembly requires administrative rights.

I've created a manifest in my C# project with:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

and all seems good: when I run:

```
bool isAdmin = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
  .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) ? true : false;
```

from my C# code, I get `isAdmin == True` as expected, but when I call a method from the VB.NET DLL with:

```
My.User.IsInRole(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.BuiltInRole.Administrator)
```

I get False instead.

This seems very illogical to me.

Furthermore, if I create a VB.NET project with a reference to this VB.NET assembly and run it with admin rights, all works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a Note in the MSDN article for My.User that could be significant:

> For Windows applications, only projects built on the Windows Application template initialize the My.User object by default. In all other Windows project types, you must initialize the My.User object by calling the My.User.InitializeWithWindowsUser Method explicitly or by assigning a value to CurrentPrincipal.

Don't hesitate to skip My.User and use the C# approach instead.